# Upload multiple files and directories

Tags: 8, files

Is there a way to upload files and directories, and make Drupal keep the structure in the destination folder?

Comment: Please include drupal version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to upload zip files, then maybe [Pack & Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/pack_upload) could work for you.

Although I haven't used this before, I would assume that folder structure would remain.

Comment: D8 verion of Pack & Upload is not updated since 2014 and needs ajustments to function but the code gave me a great insight of how I can do it myself. Thx.

Comment: That's great! If you are willing, you might want to post your solution :)